# Button to remove parent container div doesn't work on dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, html, parent

I am trying to build a to-do list javascript app from scratch. I've got everything working except for the button that removes the item from the to do list.

HTML:

```
<div class="todolistcontainer">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
class ToDoList{
constructor(){

}

createItem(){
    this.newItem = document.createElement("div");
    this.newItemP = document.createElement("p");
    this.newMinus = document.createElement("div");
}

addClasses(){
    this.newItem.classList.add('todoitem');
    this.newMinus.classList.add('minus')
}

setText(){
    this.newItemP.innerText = inputText.value;
}

appendToDocument(){
    toDoContainer.appendChild(toDoList.newItem);
    toDoList.newItem.appendChild(toDoList.newItemP);
    toDoList.newItem.appendChild(toDoList.newMinus);
}

}

minusButton.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    div.parentElement.remove();
})
})

insertButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toDoList.createItem();
    toDoList.addClasses();
    toDoList.setText();
    toDoList.appendToDocument();
})
```

Everything works except for the

```
minusButton.forEach(div => {
div.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    div.parentElement.remove();
})
})
```

It works if I pre-place the divs in the HTML file but not for the ones that are created by my JS. It's probably something simple I'm overlooking or the way I am trying to do it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through all the existing `div`s once and adding the click event listener before you add the new ones. Instead, add a click event listener to `newMinus` in the `createItem` method.

```js
class ToDoList {
  constructor() {

  }

  createItem() {
    this.newItem = document.createElement("div");
    this.newItemP = document.createElement("p");
    this.newMinus = document.createElement("div");
    newMinus.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.parentElement.remove();
    })
  }

  addClasses() {
    this.newItem.classList.add('todoitem');
    this.newMinus.classList.add('minus')
  }

  setText() {
    this.newItemP.innerText = inputText.value;
  }

  appendToDocument() {
    toDoContainer.appendChild(toDoList.newItem);
    toDoList.newItem.appendChild(toDoList.newItemP);
    toDoList.newItem.appendChild(toDoList.newMinus);
  }
}

minusButton.forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.parentElement.remove();
  })
})

insertButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toDoList.createItem();
  toDoList.addClasses();
  toDoList.setText();
  toDoList.appendToDocument();
})
```

Comment: That got me closer. The issue now is that it will only apply to the most recent div created. I tried creating a new method deleteItem() with the same event listener:   deleteItem(){
        this.newMinus.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            this.newMinus.parentElement.remove();
        })
    }                  It gives the same results, though.